# Changing JSON property value with Jquery slider

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Hello I am going to manipulate some JSON properties inside of to load some other JSON data with some jquery slider from the ui framework and I would like to know how I can access the properties inside of the JSON array and manipulate their values.

```
d3.json("basbeball.json", function(json) {
  //properties here??
  "year": '2002', //slider will modify this year
  data = json;
  counties.selectAll("path")
 .attr("class", quantize);

  //start of slider for map
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        min: 1910,
        max: 2012,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {

            $( "#sliderVal" ).val(ui.value );                
        }
    });
    $( "#sliderVal" ).val($( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have declared `data=json` and it appears to be a global variable you can read or modify the `data` object from anywhere in your code

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
      var val=ui.value ;
     $( "#sliderVal" ).val( val );  
     data.year=val;              
}
```

This assumes that `year` is a key of the json object and isn't nested in arrays or other objects

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and let you know.

Comment: What if the key is a "12345" data."12345" = val; does not work.

Comment: you aren't using proper object notation `data["12345"]` will work or `data.12345`